# Alteryx parser dynamic format XML using decision node?

Tags: xml, alteryx

I am new to Alteryx and I was being able to parser the static XML file.
However, I would like to know whether there are functions like decision node in Alteryx? I would like to build a solution for dynamic XML.

e.g. Person tag contains Name, Address, Salary
and address tag contains further tags like street, building number

I would like to know whether will it be possible to set a decision point to check whether there are address tag avaible, if so, it will check further down this tag. If not, it will continue to Salary tag.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try and put a filter tool in that checks for the xml data `contains` the XML tag as a string you're looking for; then send the `True` branch of the filter tool to an XML parse tool that parses one way, and the `False` branch of the filter to an XML parse tool that parses differently.